# Marionette CollectionView with requireJS: undefined is not a function

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, collectionview

I will explain my problem with an example. I can make this piece of code work without any problem (using MarionetteJS v1.6.2):

http://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/tvqHa

But when I try to use it with requireJs and I put it on the initialize method of a Marionette Controller, I'm Getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function backbone.marionette.js:2089

The Error comes when I define the collection view:

```
var userListView = new UserListView({
    collection: userList
});
```

I Can't figure out what is happening (this is the same code of the link above, but inside the controller initialize method)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'marionette'
], function($,_,Backbone,Marionette){
    var Controller = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
       initialize: function(){
          var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
          var UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: User
          });
          var UserView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: _.template($("#user-template").html())
          });
          var UserListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
            tagName: "ul",
            itemView: UserView,
            initialize: function() {
              this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
            }
          });

          // instances
          var jack = new User({name: "Jack"});
          var userList = new UserList(jack);


          var userListView = new UserListView({
            collection: userList
          });

          // add to page
          $("#user-list").append(userListView.render().el);

          $("#add-user").click(function() {
            var andy = new User({name: "Andy"});
            userList.add(andy);
          });
    },
    });
    return Controller;
});
```

Comment: Without having had a deeper look: This looks like a resource dependency which hasn't been loaded in the desired order. Have you configured require with a shim definition for marionettes' backbone dependency? Something like `require.config({ shim: { marionette: { deps: ['backbone'] } } });` ...?

Comment: That's how my Marionette shim looks like: 'marionette' : { deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','relational'],exports : 'Marionette' }

Comment: This is vague again, but you should possibly remove the arg `Marionette` from the defines callback function since it may clutter the object scope of inner Marionette function calls? Since Marionette extends Backbone and your entry point to Marionette objects is actually the Backbone object, this probably causes the error. Just define 'marionette' as a requirement but don't assign it - you'll never directly call it.

Comment: Perhaps `var userList = new UserList(jack);` needs to be `var userList = new UserList([jack]);` since the first argument to a collection is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine for me. I made a simple project [here.](https://bitbucket.org/jmeas/marionette-require/src/c209e55d586c?at=master)

Answer (score 2):

instead of using Backbone.Marionette in **main.js** shim : { use ***Marionette***

```
marionette: {
    exports: 'Marionette',
    deps: ['backbone']
},
```

Thus while declaring any marionette inheritance juste use Marionette instead of Backbone.Marionette as such

```
var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend

var UserView = Marionette.ItemView.extend

var UserListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend
```

For some reason the newer version or Marionette.js behave this way. I guest it produce less code.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced the Marionette 1.6.2 version with the 1.5, and now it works as it does the version without requireJs. So I think it's a release bug or something like that.